# Search both text and id with Select2.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2-4

I'm using "Select2" plugin for my select to display all "Suppliers" from my table in SQL. I used Ajax to get all Suppliers and generated `<option>` tags with value and text for my select. I bound all `<option>` tags into my select and set "Select2" function for it. I have formatted the result to display two column like this:
[image]

I read the document of Select2 for formatting the searching. But I just can search the text (the second column in the picture above).

Here is the code I used for the result formatting and searching:

```js
 //Get NhaCungCap
function GetNhaCungCap() {
    ajaxFunc("/Services.aspx/GetAllNhaCungCap", { pageNumber: 0 }, function (data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data.d);
        FillNhaCungCap(json);
    })
}
//Binding NhaCungCap
function FillNhaCungCap(json) {
    var html = "";
    $.each(json, function (k, v) {
        html += "<option value=" + v.MaNhaCungCap + ">" + v.TenNhaCungCap + "</option>";
    });

    $("#slNCC").html(html); //Bind <option> tag into select "slNCC"        
}
//Format slNCC using select2
 $('#slNCC').select2({
                placehoder: 'Tìm kiếm nhà cung cấp theo mã hoặc tên (F4)',
                escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
                data: function (repo) {
                    return JSON.stringify({ q: repo.text || repo.id, page: params.page });// search term  
                },
               
                templateResult: formatRepo,
                templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});  
//function to format Result
function formatRepo(repo) {
    if (repo.loading) {
        return  repo.id || repo.text;
    }
    var markup = "";

    markup += '<div class="row">';
    markup += '<div class="col-sm-4">' + repo.id + '</div>';
    markup += '<div class="col-sm-8">' + repo.text + '</div>';
    markup += '</div>';
    return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
    return repo.full_name || repo.text;
}
```

I'm using select2 version Select2 4.0.6-rc.1. [Link select2 from GitHub](https://github.com/select2/select2)

Comment: Please add a link to the specific documentation and indicate which version of Select2 you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the link of select2.js

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem a while ago and ended up doing a hacky thing with Select2 V4. My `<select>` element would be structured like this:

```html
<select>
  <option value="1001001">title 1||description 1 - lorem ipsum||10,00 EUR</option>
  <option value="1001002">title 2||description 2 - lorem ipsum||20,00 EUR</option>
  <option value="1001003">title 3||description 3 - lorem ipsum||30,00 EUR</option>
</select>
```

A JavaScript would then dynamically create the options for the select2 element from the text with this helper function:

```js
function formatProductSelection(product) {
  if (product.loading) return product.text; // if it's loading, don't format.
  if (product.id == 0) return product.text; // if it's an unknown ID, just return what you got.
  // Now split into product parts and create HTML source dynamically
  var dParts = product.text.split("||").filter(function (el) {
    return el != "";
  });
  var txt = '<div class="selectProductContainer">';
  txt += '<span class="productId">' + product.id + "</span>: "; // 'id' is an attribute of first function argument, same as 'text' (used above)
  txt += '<span class="productTitle">' + dParts[0] + "</span>";
  txt += '<span class="productDescription">' + dParts[1] + "</span>";
  txt += '<span class="productPrice">' + dParts[2] + "</span>";
  txt += '</div>';
  // Note the jQ - return a jquery element here of the HTML source
  return $(txt);
}
```

You attach it to the select2 like so:

```js
$("#productIdSelect").select2({
  templateResult: formatSingleResult /* not shown here */,
  templateSelection: formatProductSelection,
  theme: 'classic',
  /* ...other options... */
});
```

And lastly, with the above code, I simply added the ID to my original `<select>` element in the value of each option, which then looken like this:

```html
<select>
  <option value="1001001">title 1||description 1 - lorem ipsum||10,00 EUR||1001001</option>
  <option value="1001002">title 2||description 2 - lorem ipsum||20,00 EUR||1001002</option>
  <option value="1001003">title 3||description 3 - lorem ipsum||30,00 EUR||1001003</option>
</select>
```

Above JS code in `formatProductSelection()` ignores additional fields or values after the `||` and Select2 code searches the ID also. Maybe it helps...